# Where is located setting tab for FB application?

Tags: facebook, settings, scrollbars

I need to change IFrame to "Hide scrollbars" (vertical and horizontal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Edit settings
3. Settings /Advanced

Comment: Of course, if you have multiple apps, be sure to select the app you wish to edit in the left nav between steps 1 and 2.